# Most efficient way to remove entries in a list

Tags: python, performance, optimization, iteration

I have a massive 4D data set, spread throughout 4 variables, `x_list`, `y_list`, `z_list`, and `i_list`.  Each is a list of N scalars, with X, Y, and Z representing the point's position in space, and I representing intensity.

I already have a function that picks through and marks negligible points (those whose intensity is too low) for deletion, by setting their intensity to 0.  However, when I run this on my 2-million point set, the deletion process takes hours.

Currently, I am using the .pop(index) command to remove the data points, because it does so very cleanly.  Here is the code:

```
counter = 0
i = 0
for entry in i_list
    if (i_list[i] == 0):
        x_list.pop(i)
        y_list.pop(i)
        z_list.pop(i)
        i_list.pop(i)
        counter += 1
        print (counter, "points removed")
    else
        i += 1
```

How can I do this more efficiently?

Comment: first things first, how are you looping through the lists?

Comment: second things second. Do not use `print` while looping through 2-million points set. I bet, that 80% of this time is consumed by printing. And pop isn't best solution. Why not `.remove()` or just `del x_list[i]`?

Comment: You might want to consider NumPy. It's much better at handling large 2-D matrices, which is what you really have.

Comment: If you've got a 2'000'000 × 4 matrix, you ought be using numpy or pandas, both were written because pure Python is especially inefficient in matrix operations.

Comment: Is your list sorted? If so I reckon you can use the bisect module to perform a quick binary search.

Comment: What are you requirements for the data structure? Is insertion/deletion the most important operation? Do you need random access? Have you considered linked lists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it'll be faster to create new empty lists for each existing list, and append items to them if `i_list[i] != 0`. Look up the [time complexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) of the operations you're doing, and you'll see that deleting items is O(n), whereas appending is O(1). Currently you're doing a *lot* of O(n) deletes with a pretty large n, that will be very slow.

So something like:

```
new_x = []
new_y = []
new_y = []
new_i = []

for index in range(len(i_list)):
    if i_list[index] != 0:
        new_x.append(x_list[index])
        new_y.append(y_list[index])
        # Etc.
```

Going further, you should look into `numpy` arrays, where subsetting to find the set of items where `i_list != 0` would be very fast.

Comment: I was writing exactly same answer. Deleting item is ```O(n)``` so deleting item in loop is ```O(n**2)```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `del`:

```
array = [1, 2, 3]
del array[0]
```

gives: `[2, 3]`

And most important, using `print()` while looping through large file is suicide. Most of the time is consumed by printing. Here's example:

```
>>> from time import time
>>> def test1(n):
...     for i in range(n):
...             print(i)
... 
>>> def test2(n):
...     for i in range(n):
...             i += 1
...
>>> def wraper():
...     t1 = time()
...     test1(1000)
...     t2 = time()
...     test2(1000)
...     t3 = time()
...     print("Test1: %s\ntest2: %s: " % (t2-t1, t3-t2))
```

And output is:

```
(lots of numbers)
Test1: 0.46030712127685547
test2: 0.0:
```

Comment: `del` might be slightly faster than `pop` but both are still going to be O(n) operations- with 2 million items that's going to be very slow. You're probably  right that the print calls slow things down a bit though.

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for the happy list comprehension!

```
x_prime_list = [x for (index, x) in enumerate(x_list) 
                  if i_list[index] != 0]
```

Which pairs up members of `x_list` with their ordinal address using `enumerate()`. It puts all the members `x` in a new list, if and only if `i_list[index]` is not zero (otherwise it adds nothing to the list.

The advantage that list comprehensions have over the equivalent code you posted is that the looping and appending is handled in C rather than needing Python to do these tasks.